# Set app on Any CPU and compiled as 64bit if can be run in 32 and 64 bit. Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, registry, visual-studio-2019

It is possibile to change compiled for 64bit if application can be run in 32 and 64 bit? From what I see now, if I run applications as Any CPU, it starts as 32 bit. This would allow me to get into 64 bit registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set to 32bit by default for historical reason. The Visual Studio team never took the time to change it. Nowadays you should stick to 64bit instead.

Comment: Well, i have reason why I should leave Any CPU. Ultimately, I think I was able to download the 64 bit Registry key with the 32 bit configuration running.